# REGEXP_REPLACE explanation

Tags: sql, regex

Hi may i know what does the below query means?

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(number,'[^'' ''-/0-9:-@A-Z''[''-`a-z{-~]', 'xy') ext_number
```

Answer (score 0):

### part 1

In terms of explaining what the function function call is doing:
It is a function call to analyse an input string 'number' with a regex (2nd argument) and replace any parts of the string which match a specific string. As for the name after the parenthesis I am not sure, but the documentation for the function [is here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

### part 2

*Sorry to be writing a question within an answer here but I cannot respond in comments yet (not enough rep)*

Does this regex work? Unless sql uses different syntax this would appear to be a non-functional regex. There are some red flags, e.g:

1. The entire regex is wrapped in square parenthesis, indicating a set of characters but seems to predominantly hold an expression
2. There is a range indicator between a single quote and a character (invalid range: if a dash was required in the match it should be escaped with a '\' (backslash))
3. One set of square brackets is never closed

After some minor tweaks this regex is valid syntax:
`^'' ''\-\/0-9:-@A-Z''[''-`a-z{-~]`, but does not match anything I can think of, it is important to know what string is being examined/what the context is for the program in order to identify what the regex might be attempting to do

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is meant to replaces all ASCII control characters in the column or variable `number` with `xy`.

- `[]` encloses a class of characters. Any character in that class matches. `[^]` negates that, hence all characters match, that are not in the class.
- `-` is a range operator, e.g. `a-z` means all characters from `a` to `z`, like `abc...xyz`.
- It seams like characters enclosed in `'` should be escaped (The second `'` is to escape the `'` in the string itself.) At least this would make some sense. (But for none of the DBMS I found having a `regexp_replace()` function (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, MariaDB, MySQL), I found something in the docs, that would indicate this escape mechanism. They all use `\`, but maybe I missed something? Unfortunately you didn't tag which DBMS you're actually using!)

Now if you take an ASCII table you'll see, that the ranges in the expression make up all printable characters (counting space as printable) in groups from space to `/`, `0` to `9`, `:` to `@`, etc.. Actually it might have been shorter to express it as `'' ''-~`, space to `~`.

Given the negation, all these don't match. The ones left are from `NUL` to `US` and `DEL`. These match and get replaced by `xy` one by one.